# How does sublime text 3's search ranking works ?

Tags: search, sublimetext3, ranking, fuzzy-search

In sublime text 3, you can add folders to create a project / workspace. You can then use goto anything ( ctrl + p ) to goto a file across a project.  I know they are using fuzzy search, which I like very much. But, I could not understand the numbers that are displayed at the left of file listing. As shown in the image. How it is calculated. A ranking algorithm ? Even if it's ranking, what is the use of showing it to users.

[image: sublime ranking]

Comment: Seeing as Sublime is closed-source, there's really no way to tell without asking the author, Jon Skinner. He *very very occasionally* answers question in the [Sublime forum](http://sublimetext.com/forum), so you can ask there on the off-chance he sees it and decides to answer. Someone else *may* know, too, so it's worth a try.